# What is the Latex template for the ArXiV submission?

Tags: acm, arxiv

I want to submit an article to ArXiv. For this I have already explored Submission Guidelines from the https://arxiv.org website.

However, so far I am yet to find the template for ArXiv submission. Can I just take the [ACM Latex format](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) and use it?

https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

Comment: You can use any template. The only thing arXiv cares is if you plagiarize. If anything, don't use the peer-review option (which usually causes double line spacing). Some people plan that they will replace the double spacing version with the published version. But not all articles are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As a repository, arXiv is "template agnostic". If you're not sure which one you should use most submitters will either use `article.cls` or whichever class/style files are provided by their target journal of publication.